# Merge more than 32 files in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, apache-spark, google-compute-engine

I have an Apache Spark script running on Google Compute Engine which has for output a Google Cloud Storage. I have more than 300 part-00XXX files in my Cloud Storage folder. I would like to merge them.

I tried:

```
poiuytrez@spark-m:~$ gsutil compose gs://mybucket/data/* gs://mybucket/myfile.csv
```

But I got this error:

```
CommandException: "compose" called with too many component objects. Limit is 32.
```

Any ideas of a solution to merge all theses part files?

Comment: Partition your files into chunks with 32 files in it. Merge each individually.  Given you began with N files, you will have N/32 files now.  repeat.  If you have enough memory, you can do it with sub-command lines and wont have to read/write to disk each time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only compose 32 objects in a single request, but a composite object may have up to 1024 components. In particular, you could compose objects 0-31 into some object 0', 32-63 into 1', etc. - then each of those composite objects may be composed again by composing (0', 1',..., floor(300/32)').

Comment: Do not hesitate to let me know if someone write script to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This code composes objects from one path to `composed/` whenever the size of the composed objects hit `n` MB limit.

```
import os
from uuid import uuid4
from itertools import count

from google.cloud import storage


def delete_directory(bucket, prefix):
    print(f"cleaning temporary blobs in {prefix}")
    for blob in bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix):
        blob.delete()


def _run_compose(bucket, blob_name, blobs_to_compose):
    composed_blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    composed_blob.compose(blobs_to_compose, timeout=600)
    return composed_blob


def create_composed_blob_name(dest_prefix, offset=0):
    return f"{dest_prefix}/composed-{offset}-{uuid4().hex[:4]}.jsonl"


def compose(
    client,
    bucket_name,
    source_prefix,
    dest_prefix,
    create_new_line_blob,
    merge_when_size_mb=250,
    print_every_n_blobs=100,
):
    """

    Args:
        client:
        bucket_name:
        source_prefix:
        dest_prefix:
        create_new_line_blob:
        merge_when_size: compose when you hit `n` MB.
        merge_when_size_mb:
        print_every_n_blobs:

    Returns:

    """

    merge_when_size = merge_when_size_mb * 1024 * 1024  # MB

    bucket = client.bucket(bucket_name)

    if create_new_line_blob:
        new_line_blob = bucket.blob("tmp/new_line.txt")
        new_line_blob.upload_from_string("\n")

    blobs_to_compose = []
    composed_blob_offset = count(0)
    running_size = 0
    i = 0

    f = open("/tmp/all_composed_blobs.txt", "w")

    for i, blob in enumerate(bucket.list_blobs(prefix=source_prefix), 1):
        f.write(f"{bucket_name}/{blob.name}\n")

        if i % print_every_n_blobs == 0:
            print(f"{i} blob processed.")

        blobs_to_compose.append(blob)
        running_size += blob.size

        if len(blobs_to_compose) == 31:
            blob_name = create_composed_blob_name(
                "composed/tmp", next(composed_blob_offset)
            )
            composed_blob = _run_compose(bucket, blob_name, blobs_to_compose)
            blobs_to_compose = [composed_blob]

            # refresh all counters

        if create_new_line_blob:
            blobs_to_compose.append(new_line_blob)

        if running_size >= merge_when_size:
            blob_name = create_composed_blob_name(
                dest_prefix, next(composed_blob_offset)
            )
            _run_compose(bucket, blob_name, blobs_to_compose)
            # refresh all counters
            blobs_to_compose = []
            running_size = 0

    print(f"Last processed blob is {i}.")

    # compose the remaining, if any.
    if len(blobs_to_compose) != 0:
        blob_name = create_composed_blob_name(dest_prefix, next(composed_blob_offset))
        _run_compose(bucket, blob_name, blobs_to_compose)

    # final operations -- uploading the list of blob names & delete temporary directory.
    delete_directory(bucket, prefix="composed/tmp")
    f.close()
    bucket.blob(
        f"composed/composed-files/{os.path.basename(f.name)}"
    ).upload_from_filename(f.name)


def run():
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket_name = "some_bucket"
    source_prefixes = ["some_prefix", "another_prefix"]
    for source_prefix in source_prefixes:
        compose(
            client,
            bucket_name,
            source_prefix,
            f"composed/{source_prefix}",
            create_new_line_blob=True,
            merge_when_size_mb=250,
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: I would like to add this as a warning for anyone using bigquery `EXPORT OPTIONS` to export data. It likes to create empty files when you have small exports with many workers. It's useful to add a case to check for a non-zero size when you collect the 32 files. If none of the files have any data in them it will fail on the next iteration because the previous file didn't exist. Something like: 
`if running_size == 0:
    blobs_to_compose = [] 
    continue`